# 301 Redirect dynamic url to a rewrited url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all dynamic links to redirect to its rewritten url eg:

http://www.example.in/ads-detail.php?location=Mumbai&id=37&name=sudha-restaurant

to

http://www.example.in/Mumbai/37/sudha-restaurant

My htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /ads-detail.php?location=$1&id=$2&name=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /ads-detail.php?id=$1&name=$2 [QSA,L] –
```

Tried alot i haven't got any solution please help , Thanks in advance

Comment: please share your solution and current htaccess

Comment: This is my .htacces code 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /ads-detail.php?location=$1&id=$2&name=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /ads-detail.php?id=$1&name=$2 [QSA,L]

And Live url is : 
http://www.shoppersasia.in/ads-detail.php?location=Mumbai&id=37&name=sudha-restaurant

I want redirect to :
http://www.shoppersasia.in/Mumbai/37/sudha-restaurant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your htaccess :

```
 RewriteEngine on
#1) redirect "/ads-detail.php?location=foo&id=123&name=bar" to "/foo/123/bar"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /ads-detail.php\?location=([^&]+)&id=([^&]+)&name=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [NC,L,R]

#2) if the requested  is not for an existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 #3) then rewrite "/foo/123/bar" to "ads-details.php"
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /ads-detail.php?location=$1&id=$2&name=$3 [NC,L]
```